# Angular / Material2 - Unexpected token <

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

So I'm following this tutorial - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181888/Angular-in-ASP-NET-MVC-Web-API-Part?fid=1920478&df=90&mpp=50&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&select=5432277&prof=True&view=Thread

Every has worked great up to this point. I'm trying to add in Material 2.

The verisons I have in my package.json are:

```
"@angular/common": "4.4.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~4.4.1",
"@angular/core": "~4.4.1",
"@angular/forms": "~4.4.0",
"@angular/http": "~4.4.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~4.4.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.4.1",
"@angular/router": "~4.4.1",
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
"@angular/animations": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
```

With this I then created the mappings in the `systemjs.config.js` like so:

```
        '@angular/material':                    'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk':                         'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk.umd.js',
        '@angular/animations':                  'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
```

After I created the mappings all types were resolved with no problems. I then load up all the material components into one module called `material-component.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
    MdAutocompleteModule, MdButtonModule, MdCardModule, MdCheckboxModule, MdDatepickerModule, MdDialogModule,
    MdGridListModule, MdIconModule, MdInputModule, MdListModule,
    MdMenuModule, MdNativeDateModule, MdProgressBarModule, MdProgressSpinnerModule, MdRippleModule, MdSelectModule,
    MdSidenavModule,
    MdSliderModule,
    MdSlideToggleModule, MdSnackBarModule, MdTabsModule, MdToolbarModule, MdTooltipModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    exports: [
        MdInputModule,
        MdTabsModule,
        MdIconModule,
        MdListModule,
        MdButtonModule,
        MdToolbarModule,
        MdDialogModule,
        MdMenuModule,
        MdGridListModule,
        MdCardModule,
        MdSnackBarModule,
        MdTooltipModule,
        MdSliderModule,
        MdAutocompleteModule,
        MdDatepickerModule,
        MdSlideToggleModule,
        MdSidenavModule,
        MdCheckboxModule,
        MdNativeDateModule,
        MdProgressBarModule,
        MdProgressSpinnerModule,
        MdSelectModule,
        MdRippleModule
    ]
})
export class MaterialComponentsModule { }
```

then I finally load that module into `my app.module.ts`. Everything loads okay as seen here:

[image]

However when trying to load up the actual page to display the HTML I get this error:

[image]

```
(index):17 Error: Unexpected token <
Evaluating 
http://localhost:30815/node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk.umd.js/a11y
Evaluating http://localhost:30815/app/core/material-components.module.js
Evaluating http://localhost:30815/app/app.module.js
Evaluating http://localhost:30815/app/main.js
Loading app
at eval (<anonymous>)
at evaluate (system.src.js:2822)
at system.src.js:3625
at dynamicExecute (system.src.js:1145)
at doEvaluate (system.src.js:1092)
at ensureEvaluate (system.src.js:1000)
at system.src.js:1018
at doEvaluate (system.src.js:1090)
at ensureEvaluate (system.src.js:1000)
at system.src.js:1018
```

I cannot for the life of my figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated - if there is anything else you need please say!

Comment: Downgrade your Angular version to 4.3.x as there is currently no support for Angular 4.4.x, or at least until a PR is merged.

Comment: Upgrade your `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk` to the latest version.

Comment: Hi all,

So I've downgraded `@angular/...` to `4.3.6` and upgraded both `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk` to `2.0.0-beta.10`. Still getting the `unexpected token <`

Comment: So how do you serve the app? Is it just `ng serve`?

Comment: nope, so this is run through Visual Studio 15 - MVC4 solution.

Comment: hey, so in my `systemjs.config.js` file, I created all the mappings to the `CDK` and `Animations`. Now getting a new error saying -  `Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'md-checkbox'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154620/discussion-between-edric-and-ben-connor-hansell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you import all the modules that are required by your application:

```ts
@NgModule([
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        // And your other modules
    ]
]
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: in this case I was missing the FormsModule.

Comment: Hey Edric, thanks for the help last time! I'm now experiencing the same issue as before. @Edric